# HTML symbol get converted to random characters in databse

Tags: php, sql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I want to save HTML symbols in my database but they do get converted to random characters. I already have set every default character type to utf8_general_ci.
When I do copy-paste the string in PHPmyAdmin into the table it is rendered as question marks.

what is happening
copy "√∛∜(∑" into database colum gives output on website "???(?"
send "√∛∜(∑∫π∠≤≥<>=≠≈≉≡≢⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹·⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ" to databse is being saved as, and also being displayed on the website as:

"Ã¢ÂˆÂšÃ¢ÂˆÂ›Ã¢ÂˆÂœ(Ã¢ÂˆÂ‘Ã¢ÂˆÂ«ÃÂ€Ã¢ÂˆÂ Ã¢Â‰Â¤Ã¢Â‰Â¥<>=Ã¢Â‰Â Ã¢Â‰ÂˆÃ¢Â‰Â‰Ã¢Â‰Â¡Ã¢Â‰Â¢Ã¢ÂÂ°Ã‚Â¹Ã‚Â²Ã‚Â³Ã¢ÂÂ´Ã¢ÂÂµÃ¢ÂÂ¶Ã¢ÂÂ·Ã¢ÂÂ¸Ã¢ÂÂ¹Ã‚Â·Ã¢ÂÂºÃ¢ÂÂ»Ã¢ÂÂ¼Ã¢ÂÂ½Ã¢ÂÂ¾Ã¢ÂÂ¿"

Some additional information about the databse:

DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME : utf8
DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME : utf8_general_ci

Some additional information about the column:

Type : varchar(4096)
Collation : utf8_general_ci

UPDATE:

By adding the following line to the submit file the symbols are put correctly into the database

```
$con -> set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

Comment: Do you execute SQL command `SET NAMES utf8` on your webpage?

Comment: You can make it work, simply by changing your field collation to: **utf8_unicode_ci** you may also change the table's one to **utf8_unicode_ci**

Comment: I do execute the command $con->set_charset('utf8'); I also dont think changing the charset from utf_general_ci to utf_unicode_ci will do the trick